# Numpy.copy not working as intended for random sampling

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have an issue with [numpy.copy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) not working as intended.

When using it as following, it still references the change back in my original list, which I want to avoid:

```
test = np.copy(random.sample(population_list, 2))
test[0][0][0][0] = 1.1111
```

If I print out `population list` after the test assignment, it does replace the value in that position of `population_list` with 1.1111. My goal is to sample from the list, and then make some changes to those samples, without affecting the initial list.

As further info, my `population_list` is a list of lists, where the first element is a numpy matrix:

```
print(type(population_list))
print(type(population_list[0]))
print(type(population_list[0][0]))
print(type(population_list[0][0][0][0]))

list
list
numpy.ndarray
numpy.float64
```

LE: [This is how the data looks like](https://gyazo.com/0bd63203c87464cce1a3977df7fb0b18). Sorry for the weird format, classes are beyond me at the moment.

Comment: So you have a list of lists, and at least one element of an inner list is a numpy array of floats.  I wondered why you were repeating the `[]`, and not using something like `[0,0]`.  Do you know what `random.sample` is producing?  My guess is a couple of the nested lists.  And what is `np.copy` copying?  A list?, the array?  or something else?  Why all the nesting?

Comment: Actually it's 3 levels of list nesting.  `random.sample` keeps that nesting.  But `np.copy` wraps it in a array, producing a 4d array, unless there's some intermediate level of object dtype array.

Comment: We need to see the actual `population_list`, or at least a smaller version that behaves the same way.  Before complaining about `np.copy` we need to understand the input.  The `random.sample` part probably does not matter, since that is operating with lists.

Comment: Short version of using all the nesting is because I don't know how to use classes yet. I'm trying to copy the initial list of nested lists. As for the sample, I'm sampling 2 of the lists (and their elements) within the overall grand list if that makes sense. Thanks for the feedback, I'll be digesting your answer shortly. I'll add a screenshot of the data in a second as well, for future reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on my comments, I'll try to recreate your list

```
In [202]: x=np.arange(10.)

In [223]: x
Out[223]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

In [224]: ll=[[[x]]]    # a list

In [225]: ll[0]    # still a list
Out[225]: [[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]]

In [226]: ll[0][0]   # still a list
Out[226]: [array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]

In [227]: ll[0][0][0]    # an array
Out[227]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])

In [228]: ll[0][0][0][0]   # a float
Out[228]: 0.0

In [229]: random.sample(ll,1)  # same list nesting
Out[229]: [[[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]]]

In [230]: y=np.copy(ll)    # a 4d array

In [231]: y
Out[231]: array([[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]]]])

In [232]: y.shape
Out[232]: (1, 1, 1, 10)
```

If `ll` contained sublists of different sizes, we'll get an object array

```
In [233]: ll.append([[2]])

In [234]: ll
Out[234]: [[[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]], [[2]]]

In [235]: random.sample(ll,2)
Out[235]: [[[2]], [[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]]]

In [236]: np.copy(ll)
Out[236]: 
array([[[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]],

       [[2]]], dtype=object)  # (2,1,1) shape
```

Playing around with this some more.  If the `np.copy` is a 4d array, then modifying an element of it does not modify `ll` or `x`.  But if there is an intermediate object array level, then modifying `y` will modify `ll` and `x`.  It's more like making a shallow list copy (`ll[:]`) as opposed to a deep copy.

```
In [270]: ll=[[[x]],[[1,2,3]]]

In [271]: ll
Out[271]: [[[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]], [[1, 2, 3]]]

In [272]: y=np.copy(ll)

In [273]: y
Out[273]: 
array([[[array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]],
       [[1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)

In [274]: y[0][0][0][0]=1

In [275]: y
Out[275]: 
array([[[array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]],
       [[1, 2, 3]]], dtype=object)

In [276]: ll
Out[276]: [[[array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])]], [[1, 2, 3]]]

In [277]: x
Out[277]: array([ 1.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
```

In sum, `np.copy` does not preserve the structure of nested lists of lists.  It tries to make an array instead.  **What you should be using is `copy.deepcopy`**.  That preserves the list structure, and copies values all the way down.

Comment: Thank you very much for this very detailed answer. It made sense way faster than I normally spend on something like this.
If anyone stumbles upon here in the future, also refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy which I found quite helpful to  complement @hpaulj's reply